# Why the running time difference?

Tags: java

I tried this problem on leetcode call Plus One.

> Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits, plus one to the number. The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

One of my solution had running time of 380ms. I hardcoded some values and the running time increased to 412ms. Can anyone explain what causes this change? I thought the run time would decrease as the values will not be calculated.

Here is the code with running time 380ms:

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    int len = digits.length;

    digits[len - 1] += 1;


    if(digits[len - 1] < 10) {
        return digits;
    }
    else {
        //for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        int i = len - 1;
        while(digits[i] > 9) {

            if(i == 0) {
                int[] ans = new int[digits.length + 1];
                ans[0] = digits[0] / 10;
                ans[1] = digits[0] % 10;
                for(int n = 1; n < len; n++) {
                    ans[n + 1] = digits[n];
                }
                return ans;
            }
            else {
                int last = digits[i];
                digits[i] = last % 10;
                digits[i - 1] += last / 10;
                i--;

            }

        }
        return digits;
    }
}
```

This one took 412ms:

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    int len = digits.length;

    digits[len - 1] += 1;


    if(digits[len - 1] < 10) {
        return digits;
    }
    else {
        //for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        int i = len - 1;
        while(digits[i] > 9) {

            if(i == 0) {
                int[] ans = new int[digits.length + 1];
                ans[0] = 1;
                ans[1] = 0;
                for(int n = 1; n < len; n++) {
                    ans[n + 1] = digits[n];
                }
                return ans;
            }
            else {
                int last = digits[i];
                digits[i] = 0;
                digits[i - 1] += 1;
                i--;

            }

        }
        return digits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this is an average result, or you run it only once ? Because taking time for only 1 run, isn't so effective, because many factors could have contribute for the long run.

Comment: Are you running this on a dedicated machine with repeatable results or is the load of the machines and thus the timing of the test somewhat random?

Comment: I didn't run this on my machine. I submitted the code to LeetCode OJ and that is where I saw the run time difference.
Thanks everyone for the replies! :) There is a lot to learn and you all have added to my knowledge for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the main factors that may affect your timing results are:

- JVM warm up
- garbage collector
- compiler optimizations you don't see (reordering and so on) - for your case `ans[0] = digits[0] / 10;` `ans[1] = digits[0] % 10;` etc. may be optimized already to the fixed value, as these values never change.
- other running processes to your OS/machine that consume resources

You should warm up JVM before making your real calculations, how to do that? take some test measurements before the actual measurement (be sure that warming up takes some seconds to complete). I personally never decide when benchmark timings are less than 1 sec and I am trying to create a bigger problem to see the actual results.

If your timings for each run are too small (some ns or ms) you then have to increase the problem's size, for instance in your case, increase the size of your tables until you get some seconds on your measurements (eg try with some million of elements).

To test with smaller table sizes you always have to create a loop to measure multiple runs of your problem and then divide the total time with the number of these loop-repetitions. For instance,

```
 //after the warm up try the following
 int repetitions = 1000;
 start = System.nanoTime();
 for (int i=0; i<repetitions; i++) {
     //your calculations
 }
 end = System.nanoTime();
 System.out.println("Cost per repetition: " + (end - start)/repetitions);
```

There are some tools as well, see [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) project

Answer (score 0):

The running time of a program will depend on various factors and will usually be different. An over-simplified answer is that your computer processor has to schedule time between all the processes running and this will have an affect on the running time of your program.

If you run this on a machine with no other programs running and run this test *many* times then take the averages you can see if there is a true difference in running times.

Answer (score 0):

The program with the 380 ms:

You assign digits and and ans array hardcoded which is faster and the worse way(less readable code)

such as:

```
digits[i] = 0;
ans[0] = 1;
ans[1] = 0;
```

The program with the 412 ms:
You assign arrays with the operations or variable callings which takes more time.(that gives more readability to code)

such as:

```
digits[i] = last % 10;
ans[0] = digits[0] / 10;
ans[1] = digits[0] % 10;
```

time difference comes from this.

There also can be many possible causes makes time differences in your code respect to your coding knowledge and technique

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the condition of your computer. A process will run faster **sometimes**. You need to test the program a lot of times. Also, it is calculated in ms, milliseconds. A ms is 1/1000 of a second. It doesn't really matter if it has **few** ms difference. Divide is a very simple calculation(for computers). Modern processors can finish it in a very very very short time. You aren't using processors from 1900s.

As conclusion, you were just removing some divisions which means you will not get a big delay. Don't mind about the tiny delay ;) Your IDE might be compiling other projects when you were running the second code.